# Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config (app/duplicate-app) in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I'm trying to build a web app using firebase authentication, and I keep getting this error message. I'm using the Nextjs framework and everything should be working. I tried creating a new web app in firebase but that didn't work.

Below is the current code I have in firebase.js.

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

Below is the error message I got.

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config (app/duplicate-app).

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
components\Firebase.js (17:26) @ eval

  15 | 
  16 | // Initialize Firebase
> 17 | const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
     |                          ^
  18 | 
  19 | import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
  20 |
```

This is what pops up in the console.

```
Uncaught     at initializeApp (file:///C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/Chattr/chattr-app/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:426:33)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./components/Firebase.js:25:72)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Here is the Package.json contents:

```
{
  "name": "chattr-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.6.10",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.11.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.0"
  }
}
```

What should I do in this situation? Any help would be great.

Comment: Please add the contents of your `package.json`'s `dependencies` and `devDependencies` to your question. It is possible you are using another library that is handling the initialization for you from somewhere else like environment variables.

Comment: @samthecodingman Alright, should be added now. I installed the firebase bundle which I think should be enough. It was working fine until it wasn't for no apparent reason.

Comment: Update: It sort of just fixed itself. I don't know how or why.